# How to make plot larger Python Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, size

#### Found a biplot code that someone had made:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=countries_pivoted.columns)

def myplot(score,coeff,labels=None):
    xs = score[:,0]
    ys = score[:,1]
    n = coeff.shape[0]
    scalex = .25/(xs.max() - xs.min())
    scaley = .25/(ys.max() - ys.min())
    plt.scatter(xs * scalex,ys * scaley)
    for i in range(n):
        #Where to start arrows, format arrows
        plt.arrow(0, 0, coeff[i,0], coeff[i,1],color = 'r',alpha = 0.25)
        if labels is None:
            plt.text(coeff[i,0]* 1, coeff[i,1] * 1, "Var"+str(i+1), color = 'green', ha = 'center', va = 'center')
        else:
            plt.text(coeff[i,0]* 1, coeff[i,1] * 1, labels[i], color = 'g', ha = 'center', va = 'center')
 
    plt.xlabel("PC{}".format(1))
    plt.ylabel("PC{}".format(2))
    plt.grid()

myplot(pca_values[:,0:2],np.transpose(pca_model.components_[0:2, :]),list(x.columns))
plt.show()
```

The output works but it is very small and compressed. Any advice on how to simply make the plot itself larger??

What should I play around with to alter the size?

Saw mentions of `fig`?

(can post picture of plot if requested but I'm not sure it is needed)

Comment: try with `plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))` and increase the numbers if it is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enlarge your figure using

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
```

where `(8,8)` are the xy dimension.

Also, if you want to save a good quality image you can do

```
plt.savefig('path/to/image.png', dpi=300)
```

where the `dpi` key is the resolution in dots per inch.

Comment: where should I put that line? inside the loop or at the bottom??

Comment: When I put it at the bottom by the plt.labels and plt.grid, it creates a separate, empty plot

Comment: You should put it at the beginning, while the save fig line at the end.